# Http Client for cloud-to-device

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Hello I write application for Android with push notification, I read documentation and there client is only for server with XMPP protocol, http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html. I write application such will get data from server(time to start alarm) and it is not nessecary to do feedback. Do you have examples of HTTP client for cloud-to-device?

Answer (score 0):

The client code in the link you posted works for both XMPP connection server and HTTP connection server. The only difference is that for HTTP server you can't use the `GoogleCloudMessaging.send` method (called by the `onClick` method), because that method sends a message from device to cloud.

The handling of the registration to GCM and incoming cloud to device messages is the same for both server implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Our Http application server (cloud to device) is just an api call to an end point. This api call can be done in many ways, One is https://github.com/mseshachalam/GCMMessage-MultiCURL